# grails spring security facebook login error

Tags: grails, facebook-login, google-openid

Have no idea why this happened, it worked two weeks ago. Here is the exception log:

```
No signature of method: xxxxx.UserInfo.findAllByEmail() is applicable for argument        types: () values: []
Possible solutions: findAllByEmail([Ljava.lang.Object;). Stacktrace follows:
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: 
No signature of method: xxxxxx.UserInfo.findAllByEmail() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: findAllByEmail([Ljava.lang.Object;)
                at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi$_methodMissing_closure2.doCall(GormStaticApi.groovy:105)
                at xxxxxx.FacebookController.checkEmail(FacebookController.groovy:87)
                at xcompare.FacebookController$_closure2.doCall(FacebookController.groovy:49)
                at xxxxxxx.OpenIDFilter.doFilter(OpenIDFilter.groovy:64)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

this is the code of `FacebookController.groovy`:

```
private boolean checkEmail(String email){
    def users = UserInfo.findAllByEmail(email)
    if(users){
        // email is not available
        return false;
    }
    return true;
 }
```

and here is the code from `UserInfo`:

```
class UserInfo extends SecUser {
Provider provider
String activationCode
String firstName
String lastName
String email
Boolean active
UserType type
Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated
Category category

static constraints = {
    email unique:true, nullable:true, email:true
    provider nullable:true
    activationCode nullable:true
    firstName blank:true, nullable:true
    lastName blank:true, nullable:true
    category nullable:true      
}

String toString() {
    // normal user
    if(!openIds){
        return username
    }
    // openid user
    String name = "";
    if(firstName){
        name += firstName;
        if(lastName){
            name += " "+lastName;
        }
    }else{
        name = email;
    }
    return name;
}
```

}

Comment: Could ypu please show `FacebookController.groovy:87` and `xxxxx.UserInfo`?

Comment: sure Igor.  `private boolean checkEmail(String email){
  def users = UserInfo.findAllByEmail(email)
  if(users){
   // email is not available
   return false;
  }`  //  this is FacebookController.grovvy 87

Comment: Could you please add it to question also? not only comment

Comment: sure. newbie to stackoverflow.... thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but maybe it's because `email` is empty. So try:

```
private boolean checkEmail(String email){
    if (!email) {
        //TODO don't think that it's what you want
        return true
    }
    int count = UserInfo.countByEmail(email)
    return count == 0
}
```

Comment: yes. seems email is empty.. but it used to work weeks ago with the same code. only `grails.gsp.enable.reload = true` has been added, so will this affect?

Comment: `props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true"` has been switched to false